# AI backpropagation for a game

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, deeplearning4j

This question does not have code examples, I'm looking for an approach on how to do this.

Imagine a neural network trying to learn a game, it has 4 possible outputs (moves it can do).

In case the other player wins or gains an advantage after a (bad) move from the neural network you might want do backpropagation to teach it NOT to make this move. So you'd want to input the data [?, 0, ?, ?] to the cost function. 
... but because any other move might be OK or might not be I don't have values to input for the other moves. 
[1, 0, 1, 1] is not what I want.

How could you do the backpropagation on just 1 output? Does DeepLearning4J cater for this situation?

Thanks for any help!

R.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called reinforcement learning. DL4J offers a solution for that with RL4J, but it isn't as well documented as it should be and supports only a few algorithms.